# cfn Cluster custom AMI creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I am trying to use custom AMI (private) with cfn cluster framework. 
I have created the AMI but every time I assign the AMI ID in config file (.cfncluster/config) the "Status: cfncluster-Belle - ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS" occurs.

How can I use my own private AMI in the cfn cluster as my worker nodes ?